# Sometimes list doesn't get initialized

Tags: c#, list, initialization

**SOLVED: I figured it out myself. I can't select my answer for 2 days. Thank you everyone!**

I have this weird bug. Sometimes my list is 0, when I can't see why. Every time I stepped through the debugger, it worked. It's making me crazy. Please help! This is travelling salesperson branch and bound, by the way.

```
 public static BSSFPair generateBSSF(ref City[] Cities, int numberOfTrials)
    {
        int n = Cities.Length;

        //Declare variable for updating.
        double minCostOfBSSF = double.PositiveInfinity;
        List<int> minRandomCityOrder = new List<int>();

        //Try many random paths, and keep track of the minimum-cost path. Then select the minimum-cost path as the BSSF.
        for (int iteration = 0; iteration < numberOfTrials; iteration++)
        {
            //Choose a random path.
            List<int> randomCityOrder = new List<int>(generateRandomOrderInts(n)); //a list of ints of cities. Each city int only occurs once.

            //Determine cost of route using the TSPSolution class.
            System.Collections.ArrayList cities = new System.Collections.ArrayList(); //a list of City objects
            foreach (int i in randomCityOrder)
            {
                cities.Add(Cities[i]);
            }
            ProblemAndSolver.TSPSolution bssf = new ProblemAndSolver.TSPSolution(cities);
            double costOfBSSF = bssf.costOfRoute();

            //Update the minimums.
            if (costOfBSSF < minCostOfBSSF)
            {
                minCostOfBSSF = costOfBSSF;
                minRandomCityOrder = new List<int>(randomCityOrder);
            }
        }

        //return the path and the cost of the BSSF.

//<---- This is where the method with the bug was called.

        return new BSSFPair(minCostOfBSSF, convertCityListToEdges(minRandomCityOrder)); //<---- THIS IS WHERE THE METHOD WITH THE BUG WAS CALLED.
    }
```

**This method is where the error happens:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a list of cities (WITHOUT THE LAST CITY BEING A DUPLICATE OF THE FIRST CITY) to a list of edges
    /// (WITH THE LAST EDGE GOING BACK TO THE START OF THE FIRST EDGE because it wraps around so you can easily draw it).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="minRandomCityOrder"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<Edge> convertCityListToEdges(List<int> minRandomCityOrder)
    {
        if(minRandomCityOrder.Count < 2)
        {

//Right here->

            throw new NotImplementedException();  //<------- RIGHT HERE. minRandomCityOrder count is 0. How did that happen?
        }
        int n = minRandomCityOrder.Count;
        //Convert the BSSF path to a list of edges.
        List<Edge> newBssfPath = new List<Edge>();
        int prev = minRandomCityOrder[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            newBssfPath.Add(new Edge(prev, minRandomCityOrder[i]));
            prev = minRandomCityOrder[i];
        }
        //Add edge from end to start.
        newBssfPath.Add(new Edge(minRandomCityOrder[n - 1], minRandomCityOrder[0]));

        return newBssfPath;
    }
```

Utility function called by the code below. I've tested this myself, and it never returns an empty list.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Generate a list of ints in the range [0, (maximum-1)] (Inclusive) in a random order. Each int occurs only once in the list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="maximum"> "maximum" is the upper bound, and is not included in the list.</param>
    /// <returns>the random-ordered list.</returns>
    private static List<int> generateRandomOrderInts(int maximum)
    {
        if (maximum < 1)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        Random random = new Random();
        List<int> intsToAdd = new List<int>();
        List<int> randomOrderList = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < maximum; i++)
        {
            intsToAdd.Add(i);
        }
        while (intsToAdd.Count > 0)
        {
            //Returns a random int between 0 and n-1, inclusive.
            int randomInt = random.Next(intsToAdd.Count);
            randomOrderList.Add(intsToAdd[randomInt]);
            intsToAdd.RemoveAt(randomInt);
        }

        return randomOrderList;
    }
```

Comment: Not an answer, but consider using [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than `NotImplementedException`

Comment: I'm curious about `minRandomCityOrder = new List<int>(randomCityOrder);`. Do you *really* want a completely new list every iteration, or do you want to append to the existing list?

Comment: @JamesThorpe or still better `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. In this method:

```
  public static BSSFPair generateBSSF(ref City[] Cities, int numberOfTrials)
    {
        int n = Cities.Length;

        //Declare variable for updating.
        double minCostOfBSSF = double.PositiveInfinity;
        List<int> minRandomCityOrder = new List<int>();//<--------------here
    ...
```

It starts as empty. The problem is that this assumes that the minimum (which is initialized to infinity) will be updated, and *then* the minRandomCityOrder will get a new list initialized to it. But, if I randomly pick paths that have a cost of infinity, then it will never be updated.

So, this is what fixed my code:

```
  public static BSSFPair generateBSSF(ref City[] Cities, int numberOfTrials)
    {
        int n = Cities.Length;

        //Declare variable for updating.
        double minCostOfBSSF = double.PositiveInfinity;
        List<int> minRandomCityOrder = new List<int>(generateRandomOrderInts(n)); //<---fixed
  ...
```

Now, if it doesn't update the best solution so far, it won't break the code and will just have a garbage path to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this condition is `true` and your list gets resetted:

```
//Update the minimums.
if (costOfBSSF < minCostOfBSSF)
{
    minCostOfBSSF = costOfBSSF;
    minRandomCityOrder = new List<int>(randomCityOrder);
}
```

it does not mean that you are initializing the list with `randomCityOrder`-number of items but that the list has this initial capacity. If you want to have that number of items you might try:

```
minRandomCityOrder = Enumerable.Range(0, randomCityOrder).ToList();
```

...but I don't know if it makes sense in your algorithm. I'm just showing what's possible.

Comment: `randomCityOrder` is a `List`, which means it's using [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx), not [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z(v=vs.110).aspx) and therefore does have contents (assuming `randomCityOrder` has contents), rather than an initial capacity

Comment: I corrected `length` to `capacity`. Thx for pointing this out.